# Attaching ".input-prepend" to Bootstrap Buttons

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How can I add append input into a button in Bootstrap? [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/MgcDU/5084/) is the code which I am trying to fix, and the code is as:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="hero-unit">
    <div class="input-prepend">
      <span class="add-on">
         <i class="icon-move icon-black"></i>
      </span>
      <button class="btn btn-mini btn-info">Test Input Prepend</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It works, however, it looks like this when I use the .btn-mini class

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "mini" `input-prepend` so you'd need to customize..

```
.input-mini .add-on {
  height: 14px;
  min-width: 15px;
  padding: 4px;
  padding-top:2px;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 10px;
}

<div class="input-prepend input-mini">
      <span class="add-on">
         <i class="icon-move icon-black"></i>
      </span>
      <button class="btn btn-mini btn-info">Test Input Prepend</button>
</div>
```

### [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/63817)